# Counting the number of hits in a life cycle method using ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, lifecycle, application.cfc, coldfusion-2016

I am needing to display some analytics regarding how many times a "OnRequestStart" function is called, or rather the number of hits per hour on our internal API that’s contained in a .cfc file. Preferably through the life cycle method; however the counter must continue outside of the life cycle. I know this can be done easily in other languages, but I am new to ColdFusion and have been trying to read through the documentation to see if there is some form of life cycle method I can use in order to achieve this. If there are any sort of documentation I am missing (I've tried learn cf in a week, cfdocs, adobe documentation), but there's not really much out there. This probably isn’t 100% clear, but if there is any clarification needed I’ll be happy to help.

Edit: I figured it would be best to set an application variable in onApplicationStart and incrementally add 1 to the counter variable within the onRequest start. Here is my example code:

Application.cfc:

```
<CFFUNCTION NAME="OnApplicationStart" ACCESS="PUBLIC" RETURNTYPE="BOOLEAN">
   <cfset Application.timer EQ 0/>
   <cfset Application.counter EQ 0/>
</CFFUNCTION>
```

somepage.cfm

```
<tr> 
    <cfoutput> #Application.counter#</cfoutput>
</tr>
```

I thought this would work, but I get an error saying `Element COUNTER is undefined in APPLICATION.` Is there something I am missing? I tried to restart the CF server service and web server, but no luck.

Thank you everyone for your help

Comment: Are you wanting to write to a log or just log in the database or something? Just create a function for logging and call it in `OnRequestStart`. Is this your API or an external one?

Comment: Probably write to a log, but I also need to display the number of hits somewhere as well. Internal API

Comment: If this is your internal API, why not just log it from the API itself?

Comment: I am trying to write that into the API

Comment: Inside the API, just use something like `writeLog(text="<API_Name> Called. #application.reqCount# total calls.", type="information", file="apiLog");` in your API (assuming it's a CF API), and use Redtopia's script to also write to the `application` scope. But this will increment it every time the API is called while the Application hasn't been restarted. You may want a different division of time or a more persistent count.

Comment: The writelog function would recreate the log file repeatedly correct?

Comment: I believe `writeLog()` would create the file the first time, then write a new line to it every time the API was called. It would put the file in the CF Server's log folder. I don't think there's anything in CF's logging that will manage your log files (size, count, etc), so you'd have to handle that. You could create a task to move the log file and rename it for the interval you want, then the next time the API is called it would create a new file. I'm not sure if the `file=` attribute of `writelog()` can take a dynamic variable (maybe to include the day, or something).

Comment: I know that CF Admin can control the log files, but I'm not sure if it handles all files in the log folder or just the standard files.

Comment: Thank you Shawn, but I think I’d rather not use a log file. I don’t need the data permanently as I’ll be sending the info after a certain threshold to the administrators

Comment: I would caution again that the `application` scope would probably be easiest to do, but if the application ends before your threshold is reached, you'll lose your previous count. You may want to look into something more resilient, depending on your criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the simplest way to do this is to simply create a variable either outside of the lifecycle or within onApplicationStart then increment the variable with each onRequestStart. You can then do whatever is needed after that. One thing I did stupidly was put `<cfset Application.timer EQ 0/> <cfset Application.counter EQ 0/>` after a `<cfreturn>` tag. Lesson learned, don't assume anything, research everything haha.

Thank you everyone

Comment: Again, if your application or server dies, you'll lose your counter. You can use `onApplicationEnd()` to flush it if something causes a normal shutdown, but I don't think that will fire in a power interruption or other server crash.

Answer (score 3):

Write it to the application scope, in `onRequestStart()`, include the following code:

```
lock scope="application" type="exclusive" timeout=1 throwontimeout=false {
    if (!application.keyExists("reqCount") {
        application.reqCount= 0;
    }
    application.reqCount++;
}
```

Then you can use it whereever you need it.

Comment: Is there any documentation you'd recommend so I can understand what this is completely doing? Thank you

Comment: Great answer! The OP doesn't make it clear though if they need the count to live beyond the lifecycle of the application scope. Your answer will work but the OP should be aware that if the application restarts, the count will reset.

Comment: And depending on where this is called from, you'll want to verify what `reqCount` should start at. If it's from `onRequestStart()`, then 0 will work, but if called from within the API, you'll want to use 1, since it won't get called until the first run.

Comment: @G.Rose, I don't know where you would go for intro to CF documentation, but I imagine there are plenty of resources out there. My answer assumes a basic knowledge of what the Application scope is for and how to use it. The exclusive lock is there because multiple requests could be executing the code at the same time. The first thing I do is test to see if the variable `reqCount` exists in the Application scope. If not, it initializes it to 0. Then, it increments it. This is not something you would want to do in production because you don't want exclusive locks running on every request.

Comment: @Redtopia, this method would probably work, but it is in a production environment so I’ll have to find a different way. Sam, thank you for the clarification

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to simply add 1 to a variable outside of the life style method each time the OnRequestStart method is called?

Comment: @G.Rose, if you need to do this in production, your best bet would be to use some sort of analytics tool that aggregates your log data. Think about "fire and forget"... in other words, you log the activity and move on. Otherwise, you have no choice but to create an exclusive lock to prevent race conditions. Logging to a database would be equally bad because your db would create the lock.